# Sharepoint List Template duplicates Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i today i discovered a strange problem. 
If you Save a Template from a List with Event Receivers (for example Task List)  and add a List from that template, all Event Receivers are doubled.

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Well, we can imagine how this bugs happens. To resolve this, I would use a script Powershell in order to delete the double Event Receiver.

Comment: Yes i did this now to resolve to issue.
But i would prefer a solution not a workaround, you understand :)

Comment: My guess is when you save your list, it's save everything and the Event Receivers too. Then, when you use this template, it'll create an another list but this'll register all the save Event Receivers too. If your Event Receiver are bind to a content type, your 2 new Event Receivers are bind for the new lists and for the old lists (using the content type) too.
Have you try to bind the Event Receivers to a list url ?

Comment: Are you creating list in same site collection again ?

Comment: Vaibhav:  yes same SiteCollection. 

@ThibaultGandon this does not only happen with custom event Receivers. Tasks Lists have Event Receivers built in and they get duplicated too.